# Codeigniter Update database: echo data back in input fields and update on submit

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, updatemodel

I am developing my skills using the Codeigniter framework. I have already viewed and inserted data into the database and finding it more tricky to update data. Most tutorials i've saw are inputting the values in the code rather than pulling a selected id from the database and echoing in form fields. So far i have:

news_model:

```
function editArticle($data) {
        $data = array(
                       'title' => $title,
                       'content' => $content,
                       'author' => $author
                    );

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('news', $data, array('id' =>$id));

    }
```

Controller:

```
    public function update_entry() {
        //load the upate model
        $this->load->model('update_model');

        //get the article from the database
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_article($this->uri->segment(4));

        // perform validation on the updated article so no errors or blank fields
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'trim|required');

        // If validation fails, return to the edit screen with error messages
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->index();

        }else{
            //update the news article in the database
            if($query = $this->update_model->update()) {

        }else{
            redirect('admin/edit');
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
        <?php echo form_open('admin/edit/edit_article'); ?>

        <?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', 'Title')); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_textarea('content', set_value('content', 'Content')); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input('author', set_value('author', 'Author')); ?>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Edit Article'); ?>
        <?php if (isset($error)){echo "<p class='error'>$error</div>";
        }?>
        <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">' );?>
         <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

1) Im not sure how to echo the data out (from when the user has clicked the edit button from the article view shown) to grab that id, and then display on the edit page in the text fields.

2) And then for the user to then submit the updated data and post in the database?

Any guidance or help with structuring the rest of my controller/view files would be appreciated as ive been on this for more than a day!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given all of the code for your view, so I'm not sure how much you have right and how much you have wrong, but I'll mention a few things I can see -

You don't seem to be calling your view from your controller like `$this->load->view('edit', $data);` (see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) where the current fields' content is in `$data`.

To pre-populate the form fields, put the current field value in the second parameter of `set_value()` eg something like `set_value('title', $article->title)`.

Your model also needs to handle the submitted form (in `$this->input->post`) and then call the update query in the model.

(I have to say that the CodeIgniter docs are not great on this - you have to be looking in [Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) and [Form Validation Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) docs, as well as keeping track of Views (link above), [Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html), and [Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) (plus one or two others, I shouldn't wonder)).